# Power 5v from l298n to 5v pin arduino

Tags: arduino-mega, power, l298n

im using the l298n module, and 3x 18650 batterys (near 12v total), and supplying 12v to the 12v pin of the l298 module. Can i use the 5v pin of the module to power the 5v pin of arduino? Or i need a second power supply just for the arduino? Any tips? [image]

Comment: The L298 is a H-bridge driver, not a voltage regulator. It might be, that your L298 board has also a voltage rgulator on it. Please provide a link to that board. The datasheet mind say, how much current you can draw from it

Comment: https://www.alldatasheet.com/view.jsp?Searchword=L298N%20MODULE It has a 12v pin, ground and 5v pin

Comment: The chip has a Vss pin for the lpgic power supply. But that is not an output. The 12V will not be regulated down to 5V by this chip

Comment: I checked the 5v pin with a multimeter, and it is 5.23 volts and powered the arduino, the problem is that i dont know if it is safe or not, in my picture, the third screw withouta tire is the 5v output.

Comment: From the [amazon link](https://www.amazon.com/Qunqi-Controller-Module-Stepper-Arduino/dp/B014KMHSW6/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=L298N+Dual+H+Bridge+Stepper+Motor+Driver+Controller+Board+Module&linkCode=sl2&linkId=a8878551cf2d33142531d7734f38fe18&qid=1580505154&s=hi&sr=1-1) in the description of the linked video: "This module has a built-in 5v power supply, when the driving voltage is 7v-35v". The module has a voltage regulator. You won't get better answers, until we get a datasheet of that module with the information or at least the part number of the voltage regulator used on it.

Comment: That is something, that you can even do yourself. Look at the components on the board. Search for the voltage regulator. Look if there is a part number written onto it. Then google the datasheet. When you found it, you can look in there for the maximum output current. I would guess, the voltage regulator is the flat black IC in the middle, right besides the pins of the big L298 chip.

Comment: @JonathasMoreira 5.23V is perfectly safe

Answer (score 1):

Power the arduino from your batteries via the Vin (barrel Jack) use the arduino to supply the 5V to the L298 module and connect all the grounds together. That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

The L298N is a chip, and the link you provided in the comments is to the chip, not to a full H-bridge module with voltage regulator and other components. We don't have any way to answer your question about your particular set-up without more info.

If the module you have uses a voltage regulator to provide clean 5V to its solid state chips, but does not use it to drive the motors, and it provides enough extra current to drive your Arduino then you might be able to get away with using it to feed your Arduino. If the H-bridge module uses the output of it's 5V regulator to drive the motors then I would not recommend using it to power your Arduino, since as the motor is switched on and off it will cause the voltage from the regulator to bobble. At the very least you would need a reservoir capacitor across the 5V rails near the Arduino to smooth out the 5V supply.

Comment: Here is the module im using https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ikmDMW6tEw. I have a 1n4007 diode (https://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/872064/CHONGQING/1N4007.html) too, maybe it can help? Im afraid of inverse current, but im very noob at time to understand how things works better.

Comment: I'm not going to watch a 14 minute video to figure out what module you're using. What is the model number of the module? Do you have a data sheet?

Comment: No problem bro, you can do anything with your time, relax. I cant find the datasheet of the module, just know that use the chip l298n, and it is a very common module, but whatever, i will power my arduino with the 5v of the module. Thx

Comment: If you are going to ask questions about a specific module based on the L298n, you need to provide information about that specific module. We're trying to help you, but you need to post questions that provide enough information. Otherwise just delete your question and don't waste your time (or your readers'.)

Comment: It is simple, i have no idea how provide you the information about that specific module, the datasheet is somewhere so far away from me and i just cant find it, cause too dumb or noob to provide it. However, I endeavored to find a video that  has some information about the module, if that was not enough for you to help me, I ask you to simply ignore it and leave it to other people who can help. Thank you.